# Angular nvd3 HorizontalBarChart displayed difference format in the barLine and the holizontalLine

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js, angular-nvd3

I am creating a chart which using Angular-nvd3 library which base on nvd3 and d3.js and I have a problem that
I want to display the percent in the chart barLine and the total number in the chart horizontalLIne something looks like this:
[image]

But currently, I don't know how to do that.
I have created a plnkr: `[http://plnkr.co/edit/PygsTn?p=preview][2]`

Hope I can get some help. Thank you for taking time to look at my question.

Comment: Add your plunker link properly

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/PygsTn?p=preview access from here please.

Comment: Tooltip is possible, otherwise you might have to do with d3.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `valueFormat` property:

```
chart: {
    valueFormat: function(value){
        return Math.floor(value/TOTAL * 100) + "%";
    }
}
```

Modified plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ilaNl5KEqZa02HbWby9s?p=preview